# Differential Equation - Solve $y'=y\cot 2x, y (\frac{\pi}{4})=2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation :

$$y'=y\cot 2x,\; y (\frac{\pi}{4})=2.$$

My approach :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\cot 2x \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y}=\cot 2x dx$$

Integrating both sides we get :

$$\Rightarrow \log y = \frac{\log|\sin 2x|}{2}+c$$

$$\Rightarrow \log\left(y^2\right)= \log|\sin 2x| +c$$

Please guide further.....Thanks..

Comment: HINT: $e^{\ln y^2} = e^{\ln |\sin 2x| + c}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int \frac{dy}{y}= \int \cot 2x\; dx$$

$$\implies \;\log |y| = \dfrac 12 \log|\sin 2x| + c$$

$$\iff \log\left(y^2\right)= \log|\sin 2x| +c$$

$$\exp\left(\log\left(y^2\right)\right) = y^2 = \exp\left(\log |\sin 2x| + c\right) = C\,\Big|\sin (2x)\Big|$$

Now simply evaluate $\;y^2 = C\,\Big|\sin(2x)\Big|\;$ at $\,(\pi/4,\;2)\,$ to solve for $\;C$.